# What happen if you approach a magnet to a wire contain a current

Tags: electromagnetism

When current flow in wire, It generates a magnetic field, But there is no dipole, So how do you know what happen if you approach a magnet to wire contain a current ?

In any direction does the magnet move ?

Answer (score 0):

When magnet is placed in the magnetic field of current-carrying wire, two effects happen:

1) the magnet experiences torque to rotate it in such a way that it will be aligned with lines of force of the magnetic field of the wire; these lines form circles around the wire.

2) the magnet will be attracted towards the wire because there is general rule that body with magnetic moment, when placed in non-uniform magnetic field, is attracted towards the regions with stronger magnetic field.